# How can I get the default repo that comes with the Pop-OS distro?

Tags: apt, pop-os

I have deleted my files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and have nothing in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. I want to restore `apt` to the way it was when you install the distro. Repos and all.

Which repositories are essential to have and how can I add them in my `sources.list` file and `sources.list.d` folder?

Error when I run `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary $(lsb_release -cs) main"`

```
Repository: 'deb http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary hirsute main'
Description:
Archive for codename: hirsute components: main
More info: http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_apt_pop-os_org_proprietary-hirsute.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_apt_pop-os_org_proprietary-hirsute.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_apt_pop-os_org_proprietary-hirsute.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_apt_pop-os_org_proprietary-hirsute.list
Hit:1 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/release hirsute InRelease
Hit:3 http://apt.pop-os.org/staging-proprietary hirsute InRelease
Ign:4 http://apt.pop-os.org/staging/master hirsute InRelease
Ign:5 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:6 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Ign:7 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Ign:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Ign:9 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease
Err:10 http://apt.pop-os.org/release hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.114.110 80]
Err:11 http://apt.pop-os.org/staging/master hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.114.110 80]
Err:12 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.114.110 80]
Err:13 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.114.110 80]
Err:14 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.114.110 80]
Err:15 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.114.110 80]
Err:16 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-proposed Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.114.110 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/release hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/staging/master hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu hirsute-proposed Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: k. I'll change the question abit

Answer (score 1):

There's rather comprehensive documentation on https://apt.pop-os.org/ (easy to find using a search engine, as well).

That website lists commands to manually add these individual standard repos back. You can, should you wish so, later consolidate the sources.list.d/ files into one, but as far as I can tell, that has no advantage.

Don't have a pop!OS installation handy, but usually apt ships a minimal default sources.list in /usr/share/doc/apt/examples.

Comment: The keyserver runs succesfully. But all the other commands fail. On my terminal first it gives a couple errors about not finding some ip adresses. Then it complains about some urls not having release files along with saying that updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: "some errors". Sorry, I can't read minds.

Comment: i guess i'll edit the question to show errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages basically say that the `http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary` repository is already defined in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_apt_pop-os_org_proprietary-hirsute.list` file, **and** that most of the configured repositories no longer seem to contain the release codenamed `hirsute`.

**This is not a problem you can fix by restoring your configuration to the way it was when you installed the distro.** Instead, you must either find **if** the `hirsute` release has been archived somewhere, and if so, the correct repository URLs to point to the archive; or perform an `apt full-upgrade` to the next release after `hirsute`, which would be `impish`.

The `apt` package repository definitions for `.deb` packages have this format:

```
deb|deb-src <repository URL> <release codename> <section name...>
```

In plain language: the line begins with a keyword that is either `deb` or `deb-src`, then there is a repository URL, release codename, and one or more section names, all separated by spaces.

When `apt` is accessing the repository, it puts these elements together to form actual URLs like this:

```
<repository URL>/dists/<release codename>/<section name>
```

The `<release codename>` is what the `lsb_release -cs` command outputs; apparently, it is `hirsute` for your system's current state.

Following this syntax, you can often build actual URLs and visit them with a regular web browser to verify the state of the repositories:

- [`http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary/dists/`](http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary/dists/): the directory exists and contains sub-directories for releases `bionic`, `disco`, `eoan`, `focal`, `groovy`, `hirsute`, `impish` and `jammy`. The `hirsute` sub-directory contains the appropriate repository metadata files, and a sub-directory for the `main` section, which contains sub-directories for each released binary architecture, and a separate sub-directory `source` for source packages. This part of the repository is usable to you as-is.
- [`http://apt.pop-os.org/release/dists/`](http://apt.pop-os.org/release/dists/): the `hirsute` sub-directory does not exist. Only `impish` and `jammy` are present.
- [`http://apt.pop-os.org/staging-proprietary/dists/`](http://apt.pop-os.org/staging-proprietary/dists/): just like the `proprietary` repository above, this repository seems usable to you as-is.
- [`http://apt.pop-os.org/staging/master/dists/`](http://apt.pop-os.org/staging/master/dists/): the `hirsute` sub-directory does not exist. Only `bionic`, `focal` and `jammy` are present.
- [`http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu/dists/`](http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu/dists/): lots of sub-directories there, but no `hirsute`, `hirsute-security`, `hirsute-updates`, `hirsute-backports` nor `hirsute-proposed`. Since the URL mentions `ubuntu`, this seems to be the repository for packages Pop!_OS essentially copies straight from the corresponding release of Ubuntu. The end-of-support date for Ubuntu 21.04 "Hirsute Hippo" was 2022-01-20, meaning that Pop!_OS no longer can have upstream support for this release.

According to [Wikipedia's release table for Pop!_OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop!_OS#Release_table), general support for your current release of Pop!_OS ended 2022-01-22, and the support for the *next* release already ended at the end of July 2022. The current release is 22.04 LTS (codename `jammy`), and it is a Long Term Support release, so it would be best to get to that release if you can. But updating to 22.04 is only possible from either 20.04 (= the previous LTS release) or the 21.10 (= `impish`, the release just before the latest one).

According to [Pop!_OS upgrade instructions](https://support.system76.com/articles/upgrade-pop/), one of the last updates to the old release should have enabled the option to upgrade to the new release. But you've waited for too long, and System76.com has already removed most of the repositories for `hirsute` as obsolete, which is causing most of your current problems.

**At your own risk**, you might try the following to get to the `impish` release:

1. Backup all important data.
2. Edit the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, replacing any occurrences of the release keyword `hirsute` with `impish`.
3. Run `sudo apt update` and verify it runs without errors.
4. Run `sudo apt full-upgrade`. If it stops with an error, try running it again until it reports it has nothing further to update. Then reboot and hope for the best.
5. If successful, you should now be at version 21.10 "`impish`", which you can still update to the current release by following the update instructions from system76.com (see link above).